# Unable to connect to shared (iscsitarget) dvd-rw drive on ubuntu karmic box

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, iscsi

### Intro

I have desktop with DVD-RW drive that runs primarily on Linux (namely Ubuntu 9.10). My wife has netbook that rins Windows XP with no cd/dvd drive. There's also LAN through our ADSL modem/router. I've "ported" (actually, I've just grabbed sources and ran `dpkg-buildpackage`) `iscsitarget` package from Ubuntu Lucid to Karmic ([here are packages](https://launchpad.net/~develop7/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/985837/+listing-archive-extra)), installed it (`sudo aptitude install iscsitarget; sudo m-a a-i iscsitarget`) and configured it in the following way (`/etc/ietd.conf`):

```
Target iqn.2020-01.local.develop7-desktop:storage.disc.dvdrw
Lun 0 Path=/dev/sr0,Type=blockio
#I've skipped commented lines
```

Also, I've opened port 3260 with `ufw`:

```
$ sudo ufw status | grep 3260
3260                       ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
```

### Problem

But (here's the trouble) I still can't connect to this target from Windows box. Microsoft Software iSCSI Initiator screams "Logon failure" upon connect attempt, and, respectively, fails to connect. After unsuccessful connection attempt I've noticed this line in `dmesg | tail`'s output:

> ```
> iscsi_trgt: ioctl(299) invalid ioctl cmd c078690d
> ```

### Question

So the question is — what's wrong with my config/iSCSI target/whatever else? Or, in short — what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Nabble thread](http://old.nabble.com/ioctl%28301%29:-invalid-ioctl-cmd-on-Ubuntu-2.6.28-under-VirtualBox-td26600769.html) indicates this could be a consequence of an old IET kernel module included in Ubuntu's kernel.  Check the thread closely and see if your symptoms align.  This might make sense, since there seems to be a huge difference in versions between Karmic's official *iscsitarget* package and the version you're attempting to backport.

If so, the fix seems to be to find and disable the old module:

> the original kernel module on Ubuntu is at:
>   `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/ubuntu/iscsitarget/iscsi_trgt.ko`, and it's necessary
>   to run `depmod -a` to regenerate modules.dep before attempting to load the new module,
>   e.g.:
>
> ```
> mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/ubuntu/iscsitarget/iscsi_trgt.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/ubuntu/iscsitarget/iscsi_trgt.ko.orig
> depmod -a
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me.
I've renamed .ko and noticed there's no new .ko for current kernel. So I've ran `m-a a-i iscsitarget-source` in current kernel and now I'm able to connect to target.

Comment: good deal.  i wondered if there wasn't a missing step, since the Karmic *iscsitarget* package doesn't install a module itself, but it sounds like you found the right step.